# href in anchor tag is removed by yahoo mail client

Tags: html, css, yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-mail

below is the email template snippet code that is sent in a mail:

```
<a href="https:&#x2F;&#x2F;someurl.net&#x2F;reset-password?passwordResetToken&#x3D;Qlc9CFIj8NziJEFuDFXv0uDHZTlzhMbj" style="font-family: 'arial',sans-serif; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding: 10px 10px;">TROQUE SUA SENHA</a>
```

**yahoo** renders to something like, (**missing href**)

```
<a rel="nofollow" style="font-family:'arial', sans-serif;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;padding:10px 10px;">TROQUE SUA SENHA</a>
```

gmail renders to something like, (which is correct)

```
<a href="https://someurl.net/reset-password?passwordResetToken=OwNWeKbhoK8TaklFdJRIQWTi7dmCI93A" style="font-family:'arial',sans-serif;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;padding:10px 10px" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://someurl.net/reset-password?passwordResetToken%3DOwNWeKbhoK8TaklFdJRIQWTi7dmCI93A&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1588314607785000&amp;usg=AFQjCNEjn0R1PYzmZsDWVFxNzvIhjWG8_A">TROQUE SUA SENHA</a>
```

Is there any specific anchor tag attribute that should be set to render `<a>` tag in yahoo client?

Comment: Perhaps you are escaping too eagerly some characters (your `/` and `=` shouldn't need to be escaped).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it resolved, when replaced the [html entity hex](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/sidehtmlentity.html) in href url from `&#x2F;` to `/`

```
rawTemplate.replace(/&#x2F;/g, '/')
```

Observed that the `gmail` mail client handles both html entity hex for slash(`&#x2F;`) and slash(`/`), so was able to get the correct anchor link after rendering.

But the `yahoo` mail client handles only slash(`/`) while rendering so had to manually replace

Comment: This replace method fixed the issue for us in Yahoo. Thanks a ton!